# Removing rows surrounding a grepl pattern match in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, grepl

I would like to remove rows from a dataframe in R that contain a specific string (I can do this using `grepl`), but also the row directly below each pattern match. Removing the rows with the matching pattern seems simple enough using grepl:

```
df[!grepl("my_string",df$V1),]
```

The part I am stuck with is how to also remove the row below the row that containings the pattern that matches `"my_string"` in the above example.

Thank you for any suggestions anyone has!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep` you can get the row number where you find a pattern. Increment the row number by 1 and remove both the rows.

```
inds <- grep("my_string",df$V1)
result <- df[-unique(c(inds, inds + 1)), ]
```

---

Using `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

result <- df %>%
  filter({
    inds <- str_detect("my_string", V1)
    !(inds | lag(inds, default = FALSE))
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. Both of those solutions look like they should do what I would like. Though I haven't been able to get either to work. This may be my inexperience, sorry! In the case of the first solution I get the following error message: "Error: unexpected ']' in "result <- gene[-unique(c(inds, inds + 1), ]". In the case of the second solution (using dplyr & stringr) I get the full dataframe returned. So it has not removed any lines. Do you have any suggestions as to where I may be going wrong?

Comment: @EmilyO'Connor Try the updated answer. I have created a new object `result` to store the result which you can check for the output.

Comment: @EmilyO'Connor You get the error because you did not close the paranthesis, ie you should have `result <- gene[-unique(c(inds, inds + 1)), ]`. Take NOTE of the 2 closing paranthesis after 1. You only have 1

Comment: @RonakShah Ahh yes, now I see it! Thank you, that solution works perfectly.

Comment: @RonakShah Is the command 'unique' necessary?

Comment: No, it is not necessary but I used it on safer side if the two consecutive rows has "my_string" then it might create the same index twice.